# change css on changing resolution of desktop screen

Tags: javascript, css

my website looks like this on 100% resolution

[this is my 100% resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BPED.jpg)

But, when i make resolution to 90% by pressing the combination of 'ctrl' and '-'
it is overlaping like this:

[this is my 90% resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccwj0.jpg)

how to define css for 90% resolution

Plz help me.

Comment: The way wouldn't be to define CSS for 90% but making your elements floating correctly...

Comment: [this might help you](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Please add your code , so we can fix it, Otherwise use Media query , css3 and HTML5 component, and made relative layout not use static data

Comment: It's floating issues. You have an unnecessary clearfix div (second parent div in <body>) that should be deleted. Then the container div should be cleared left.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use *flexbox* to avoid this sort of troubles. Very powerful thing.
Gives you full control over blocks, also responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Changing css based on resolution or device type will be possible only with. MediaQueries.

Example:

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 

  .your_desired_class{
    background-color:red;
  }

}
```

You can play with `min-device-width`

Find the basic in http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp